# Updating record in phpmyadmin with php code

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, updates

I have a reservation form where once it is filled out, the rooms available for a certain building are decreased by one. I am using Cloud9 ide with php to update the record for that building in the phpmyadmin database. I think the equation to subtract one room from roomsAvailable is not being read. It might be as simple as an issue with quotes.

This is the update:

```
$sql = "UPDATE $dormTable SET roomsAvailable = --$dormRecord[roomsAvailable] 
        WHERE id = $dormRecord[id]";
```

This is the output on the webpage when i echo the statement and the dorm record:

```
"UPDATE `dorms` SET `roomsAvailable` = --5 WHERE `id` = 8"

Array ( [id] => 8 [name] => Lower West Cedar St. [class] => 2 [specialNeeds] => 1 [laundry] => 1 [fullyEquippedKitchen] => 1 [roomsAvailable] => 5 [roomsReserved] => 0 [roomCapacity] => 5 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need  the value of  --$dormRecord[roomsAvailable]   you shuold use string concatenation for $sql

In this way the php code is execute and the result is concatenated  with query

```
$sql = "UPDATE $dormTable SET roomsAvailable = "  .  --$dormRecord[roomsAvailable]  .
     "  WHERE id = $dormRecord[id]";
```

you can see thye result using

```
echo  $sql ;
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! I'm still a little unsure of how to input this in the database in phpmyadmin though as an echo"\"$sql\"" doesn't work.

Comment: If the record in my database isn't updating, is the problem most likely with the connection? Even though the record of my reservation that I make does get inputted into the database.

Comment: You should check for connection .. and be sure you have a valid connect  otherwsir the php server should raise an exception .. .. but mostly  your should be sure you execute the query .. in your code you have just write a qiery but not executed..

Answer (score 0):

I think this would better solution

```
$sql = "UPDATE dorms  SET roomsAvailable = roomsAvailable-1 WHERE id = $dormRecord[id]";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should this be a "better solution"?